# What app can I use to create mixtapes?

Tags: mac, mix, podcasts, applications

As a huge mixtapes/weekly mixs listener and music addict, I always wanted to try it myself, share some tracks and create/modify/mix songs and stuff to create like an "universe" for it. Here is [an example](https://soundcloud.com/izemsounds/izem-show-124-lindigo-am-shawn-lee-banda-de-pifanos-de-caruaru-exclusive-izem-album) of what I'm looking to achieve.

I tried Adobe Audition without so much difficulties, but it doesn't feel great and accurate for stuff like that (BPM and sound levels sync, etc). Then Ableton Live, but here I'm completely lost (maybe more adapted for electronic music podcasts?).

Then I was wondering which app can I use to create mixtapes (I'm on Mac)? Also looking for creating intros, outros and interludes from different tracks and sounds, then a multi-track app is better I guess?

PS: I don't have that much knowledge about sound in general

Answer (score 2):

What I would advice would be to use a mixing software like **[Native Instruments - Traktor](http://www.native-instruments.com/fr/products/traktor/dj-software/traktor-pro-2/)** for mixing tracks together.

If you prefer non-live mixing you should definitely learn how to use a software like **[Ableton - Live](https://www.ableton.com/en/live/)**.

Your setup may vary depending on your needs, but one important thing in a live mix is not recording an audio feedback from your microphone.

you monitor every sounds through your headphones and cut your mic input (gate) while you don't speak.

Once thing though, is that you can take advantage of both softwares (Live for the voice and Traktor for the music) by using them at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Ableton - Session View. You can drag each clip onto a track and set the global BPM (the clips will automatically fall into time with each other) - then draw in the fades and such.

There are several algorithms to choose from to make the time adjustment sound more natural. I prefer to leave it on beats > transient.

This is all super easy if the clips are already cut to loops. If you are dragging something in that has a hard to determine BPM, then you need to adjust the warp marks in the clip, or slice the wave into smaller loopable clips in a direct wave editor like Audition.

I think the intro version is $99.

Answer (score 0):

A key thing to understand is that you don’t want some audio software like Adobe Audition. What you want is a musical instrument like Ableton Live or Traktor. And you are going to have to work at that instrument in order to master it, no matter which one you choose. So it is good to try a number of options, find one that you really like, and then roll up your sleeves and get your hands really dirty with it. You’ll get closer and closer to the results you want with each session.

Note that you don’t just want a Mac software app. Whatever software you choose, you want a combination of a Mac app and some kind of external controller. For example with Live, you can use an iPad app called touchAble ($25 I think) or a hardware Novation LaunchPad ($65 or so for the mini) to play. On the Mac, you basically create your own instrument with Ableton Live (by loading the mixer with audio clips, MIDI clips, audio effects, software instruments) and then you arm the global automation record and you play your instrument from the controller and Live records your playing into the Arrangement view. You want to be able to launch 2 clips at the same time, you want to be able to slide multiple faders up and down, you want to be able to turn filter knobs, and so on. All that happens on the external controller. If you use the mouse on the Mac to play your instrument, you will be very limited and it is not a very creative experience and you will get markedly worse results.

So you are shopping for something like Traktor plus a turntable controller, or Live plus a LaunchPad or iPad app.

Feeling lost at first in Live is OK. But it is actually fairly easy to learn. Everything is in one window where you can see it and gradually learn each feature, and if you choose View ▶ Info from the menus, then whatever you hover your mouse over will be explained at the bottom left of the Live window. There are many great tutorial videos on YouTube and a large community of users to help if you get stuck. Live is not setup to be easy for a new user so much as it is setup to be very fast and capable for an experienced user during a live performance, so it does require you to watch some tutorial videos and read the manual to get the lay of the land. But it very quickly stops being mysterious.

But again, try a bunch of options. Don’t rush into anything. You have a special opportunity to choose an instrument that you can really bond with and make the music that you’re dreaming about making. If there is a musical instrument store near you, go and try a bunch of hardware interfaces. You might find one that really feels right and whatever software goes with it is a secondary consideration.